# Using calendar in emulator

Tags: android, calendar, emulation

I'm new here and I'm trying to develop my first App for android.

Now I have the problem, that on the emulator (configured with Google API 8, the same I have on my Samsung Galaxy I9000, I think!), I don't have the calendar and the contacts App is other as on my phone, too...

I tryed to install the same App I have on my phone (backed up with TitaniumBackup), but I get the error INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT.

Since my App should manage the calendar, I need it...

I read many topics in this forum, and I see, that I'm not alone with this problem, but the suggested solutions didn't work for me...

Alternatively, are there an Image of the Galaxy I9000 for the emulator?

Comment: could you please say what solutions you tried and didn't work?

Comment: If you search here for android emulator calendar, you can find many posts, but no one worked by me... I can have a calendar, that I can't use (it says, that I don't have a calendar), or asked for a Google-Account, but can't log in, or just didn't start.

Comment: I won't search for posts that maybe didn't help you. It should be you to say what methods you tried and what went wrong with them...I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) reading might be very helpful